# access to nth element of set

Tags: c++, stl, set

There is a set `visited`. And I wanna check all its elements from 4-th to last.
I'm trying to do something like that

```
int visited_pointer = 4;
for ( set<int>::iterator i_visited=visited.begin()+visited_pointer
    ; i_visited!=visited.end()
    ; i_visited++
)
```

and got errors with `operator+`.

How can I do that in the right way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That usage of `operator+` is only provided for random-access iterators.  `set` iterators are bi-directional iterators.

But the function `std::advance` can be used to move any iterator a certain number of places:

```
#include <iterator>

//...

set<int>::iterator i_visited = visited.begin();
for ( std::advance(i_visited, visited_pointer)
    ; i_visited!=visited.end()
    ; ++i_visited
)
```

Answer (score 2):

sets do not support random access iterators (i.e. ones that support adding values to an iterator), so the only way to do this is to iterate through the first (whatever that may mean) four members until you get to the one you want. It sounds to me like set is not the right container for whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Re: "whatever that may mean": a set is an ordered container, and the first member is the one that comes first according to that ordering.

Comment: @Mike True. I must admit I'm accustomed to thinking of sets as being like smalltalk "bags", with no order and the set's ordering function only being used to guarantee uniqueness. But that's just me.